# Is new instance of class created per each implicit class conversion?

Tags: scala, implicit

```
object test extends App {
  implicit class f(i: Int) { println("!!!"); def f = 42 + i }
  1.f
  2.f
  3.f
}
```

In .class file we see

```
public static test$f f(int);
  Code:
     0: getstatic     #16                 // Field test$.MODULE$:Ltest$;
     3: iload_0
     4: invokevirtual #42                 // Method test$.f:(I)Ltest$f;
     7: areturn
```

So, looks like there is a static method, but this code prints "!!!" 3 times when run. Do we have new class instantiation per each implicit class conversion? If yes, why? If no, why "!!!" was print thrice?

Comment: I don't see any new classes being created here. Can you clarify?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Each time you run `1.f` you create and allocate new instance of class `f`.

Comment: You do in theory, but the JVM is clever enough not to *actually* create them if it doesn't need to. So it won't be any slower than using a static method. I don't have proof to hand, but you can try it if you want.

Comment: @dveim: Sure, but that's not creating a new class, so I still don't see how any new classes are created.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Renamed question to clarify.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge JVM might be smart enough to eliminate unnecessary class, and might be not. In any case, one should not load it intentionally.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid instantiating your extension class by making it a [*value class*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html)

```
implicit class f(val i: Int) extends AnyVal { def f = 42 + i }
```

Note, that then you can't put `println` inside, but here's a quote from the docs linked above:

> At runtime, this expression 3.toHexString is optimised to the equivalent of a method call on a static object (RichInt$.MODULE$.extension$toHexString(3)), rather than a method call on a newly instantiated object.

Comment: I know about `AnyVal`s, my question was about "what happens" and "why that happens" ?

Comment: I mean, why create a static method and don't employ that you don't need to create new class each time because it's _static_ ?

Comment: OK, I can't explain that. But my best guess is that it happens exactly because it's a class with a non-static initialization block. I think that if you made an implicit conversion to an `object` with that method `f`, it would be a real static method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - implicit Class is shorthand for the creation a class and implicit def for creating an instance i.e. in your example:

```
object test extends App {
 class f(i: Int) { println("!!!"); def f=42+i}
 implicit def toF(i : int) = new f(i)
}
```

Comment: So that's compiled to static method. Why scala still create new class each time, static methods don't need that? Or, for example, scala could cache that `f` instance.

Comment: 1. An instance of `f` is created because that's what the body says to do: `new f(i)`. 2. Instance couldn't be cached because different instances have different constructor arguments.